# While using navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.finuc1); func1 can't relate to the other function

Tags: angular, weather-api

So fist of im using angular and wanted to download current geological coordinates and send them to my api.When i run this code it shows error " Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getData') ".Im sure that the getData function is working becouse when i refer to it somewhere else for example : this.getData(a,b) (a and b is given by a user) everyfing goes fine.Here is my code:

```
  showPosition(position:any) {
    let g = position.coords.latitude;
    let f = position.coords.longitude;
    this.getData(g,f);
  };
  
  getLocation() {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.showPosition);
  };

  getData(lat:any , lng:any) {
    this.httpClient.get(`https://api.open-meteo.com/v1/forecast?latitude=${lat}&longitude=${lng}&hourly=temperature_2m,relativehumidity_2m,windspeed_10m`)
    .subscribe((res:any) => {
      this.weatherData = res;
      this.findTodayDate();
    });
  };
```

I tried moving the whole getData func to show position but then i had problem with httpClient. i tried to give static numer to the show position like

```
showPosition(position:any) {
    this.getData(23,23);
  };
```

but got the same error i think that problem is with the way that navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.showPosition); uses funcions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition instead:

```
  showPosition() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        (position) => {
          console.log(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude)
          let g = position.coords.latitude;
          let f = position.coords.longitude;
          this.getData(g, f);
        }
      );
      }
  };
```